# How can I collect windows event logs (System event log, Application event log) from AKS pods?

Tags: azure, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod

To debug a pod, we would require windows system event log and application event logs from that particular pod.

Is it possible to collect the above mentioned logs rather than using 'kubectl log' command?

Answer (score 0):

`kubectl log` only collects the data from STDOUT & STDERR. As long as your application does not send logs to STDOUT & STDERR, you will be not able to see those with `kubectl logs`.

As a temp workaround you can use `kubectl exec` to locate your logfiles and then `kubectl cp` to copy those to your local pc.

A more sophisticated way would be a sidecar container which collects to logs and send it central logging solution.

A still suggest to use STDOUT & STDERR bcs this integrates with Azure Monitor & Insights.